# How to arrange items in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="item1">Item1</div>
    <div id="item2">Item2</div>
    <div id="item3">Item3</div>
</div>
```

How to arrange the items, I want item 2 and 3 appears block, so that item 1 is inline with the block element consisting of item 2 and item 3.  The height of item 1 is the same as the height of item 2 and item 3 as one.

Comment: Please modify your question to include all relevant code and desired output

Comment: Should their height be assigned dynamically, and each _column_ have the same height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `flexbox` approach:

```css
#item1 { height: 200px; }
#item2, #item3 { height: 100px }
#item1 { background: yellow; }
#item2 { background: green; }
#item3 { background: blue; }

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="item1">Item1</div>
  <div id="item2">Item2</div>
  <div id="item3">Item3</div>
</div>
```

Simple `float` and no `flexbox` appropach:

```css
#item1 { background: yellow; }
#item2 { background: blue; }
#item3 { background: green; }

#item1 { 
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#item2, #item3 {
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="item1">Item1</div>
  <div id="item2">Item2</div>
  <div id="item3">Item3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely because this solution only works properly in theory, as when one start adding content, the fixed height will for sure become a problem given the fact that OP wants each _column_ to have the same height. And FYI, I was not down voting.

Comment: "The height of item 1 is the same as the height of item 2 and item 3 as one." - what I grasped from it: `1.height == (2.height + 3.height)`.

Comment: Yes, but how should that be controlled if content says otherwise? ... So that is most likely the reason you got down voted.

Comment: I see, but downvoting seems pretty harsh, considering the quality of the question itself. Whatever.

Comment: Yeah, hence I didn't, still, avoid answer low quality question and you won't get down votes, which actually can be another reason users down vote.

Comment: Thanks @wscourage

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!